# I want to remove a td from ng repeat ui-route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, sequelize.js

Alright what i want  to do is pretty simple. 
I have a table like this :

```html
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <td>{{message.id}}</td>
            <td>{{message.subject}}</td>
            <td>{{message.content}}</td>
   <td>{{message.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

In my server.js i wrote the api like this

```html
app.delete('/messages/:id',function(req,res){
    var idm = req.params.id
    Message.find({
        where : {
            id : idm

        }
    })
    .success(function(messsage) {
        Message.destroy({
            where :{
                id :idm
            }
        })

            .success(function(){
                res.status(202).send('deleted message')
            })
    })
    
})
```

And in the controller I tried using

```html
    $scope.deleteMessage = function(message){
        var idm=$state.id
        $http.delete('/messages/'+idm,message)
        .succes(function(){
            $scope.status='deleted'
            $state.go($state.current,{},{reload : true})

        })
        .error(function(){
            $scope.status = 'not deleted'
        })


    }
```

When I click the buton i have in my view aka :

```html
 <input type="number" ng-model="message.id" placeholder="Id to delete" />
```

The code runs in the backend and it says : Executing delete from messages where id='undefined' . So i guess the problem is i don't pass the id corectly.

I tried using postman to make a delete request for a certain id and it works.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: change $http.delete('/messages/'+idm,message) to $http.get('/messages/'+idm) and try!

Comment: Do you added $scope.message in the controller ? Plz copy all controller and HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was so simple :

```
 $scope.deleteChampion = function(champion){ $http.delete('/champions/'+champion.id) $state.go($state.current,{},{reload : true}) } all i had to do was add " + champion.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using angular ui-router. Try changing `$state.id` to `$stateParams.id` guessing the `$state` has `/messages/:id` as url. [More info](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters)

```
$scope.deleteMessage = function(message){
    var idm=$stateParams.id
    $http.delete('/messages/'+idm,message)
    .succes(function(){
        $scope.status='deleted'
        $state.go($state.current,{},{reload : true})

    })
    .error(function(){
        $scope.status = 'not deleted'
    })
}
```

---

Btw, (and not related to the question) one way to improve your `server.js` file is as following:

```
app.delete('/messages/:id',function(req,res){
  var idm = req.params.id
  Message.find(idm)
    .success(function(messsage) {
      message.destroy()
        .success(function(){
            res.status(202).send('deleted message')
        });
    });
});
```

or:

```
app.delete('/messages/:id',function(req,res){
  var idm = req.params.id
  Message.destroy({where: {id: idm}})
    .success(function(affectedRows) {
      if (affectedRows == 1) {
        res.status(202).send('deleted message')
      } else {
         // something went wrong and none or more than one messages were deleted
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer i managed to fix the issue on my own and i forgot about this topic. it was so simple :          $scope.deleteChampion = function(champion){
        
        $http.delete('/champions/'+champion.id)
          $state.go($state.current,{},{reload : true})

    }    all i had to do was add " + champion.id"

Comment: you should put your solution as another answer, so everyone could check / see it @mariusraiu